# What is the HIVE equivalent to MySQL's SET column type?

Tags: mysql, database, hadoop, hive, hbase

I have a bunch of MySQL which I need to manually convert to HIVE tables.

Most of the MySQL column types, such as bigint(#), INT(#), varchar(#), ... Have straight forward conversiona.

However, I have a table with column:
' columnName SET( 'v1', 'v2', ... , 'vn')'

I'm not sure  how to convert this column. I did some reading and it doesn't look like HIVE supports sets. Should I just name the hive type type('v#')?

Comment: can you add sample meaningful query ?

Comment: BTW, Hive supports most of the MySQL keywords and syntax

Answer (score 0):

Below are Complex Datatype supported by Hive:

- arrays
- maps
- structs
- union

You can create struct depending upon your datatype need.